# Vectorized transition matrix reduction

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to find a wizard's vectorization for the following iterative computation (please look at the later edit):

```
% A is a logical matrix of size NxN
B = false(size(A));
for k1 = 1:N, for k2 = 1:N, for k3 = 1:N
        B(k1,k2) = A(k1,k2) && ~A(k1,k3) && ~A(k3,k2);
end; end; end;
```

I must stress out that solutions using `arrayfun` (or `structfun` or `cellfun`) are not feasible since they are slow, and I'm looking for performance improvement, not expressiveness enhancement. <s>Also, I'd like to avoid the obvious:</s>

```
B = A & logical((1-A)^2)
```

because the memory footprint for computing this is 17 times the original's (and I work with big matrices in an eventually fragmented memory resource).

A positive answer (i.e. a solution) or a negative one (i.e. an explanation why this cannot work) are both greatly appreciated.

**Later edit**

Thanks to [H.Muster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351522/h-muster) I became aware of a bug in my initial code. The iteration to be vectorized is actually:

```
% A is a logical matrix of size NxN
B = A;
for k1 = 1:N, for k2 = 1:N, for k3 = 1:N
        B(k1,k2) = B(k1,k2) && ~(A(k1,k3) && A(k3,k2));
end; end; end;
```

A faster iteration is welcome also (I'm studying this right now, if I find something I will post as comment/edit).

**Even later edit**

For those who are interested in the *purpose* of the code, it's supposed to compute the [transitive reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) `B` of a relationship graph `A`. `A(k1,k2)=true` means that `k1` "relates to" `k2` (the reciprocal is not true). `B(k1,k2)=true`means that `k1` "relates to" `k2` and there is no other element `k3` "between" them, i.e. `k2` is the "next" after `k1`. One must note that, if defined like this, an element may benefit of several "next" elements, not only one. The transitive reduction helps creating "non-deterministic iterators" (next is a set, not a single element) into set structures "induced" by a non-symmetric [dyadic relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation).

Comment: Doesn't the inner loop overwrite the values in `B(k1,k2)`, resulting in only the value for `k3==N` being stored in `B`?

Comment: my guess us that  `ismember` will be useful...

Comment: @H.Muster Oh, thanks to your comment I just discovered a bug in my code. I was *so* trying to optimize a wrong answer... :D I will update the code to reflect what actually I wanted.

Comment: @natan `ismember` is really hard to use when all values are either `true` of `false`. How would you know which is which? Or maybe I didn't understand fully your suggestion. Would you like to elaborate more on your idea, please?

Comment: your triple loop solution might benefit from early-exit optimization (as soon as B(i,j) becomes false, skip to next element)

Comment: @Amro: that's right, it's what I thought first, to emulate the lazy '&&' by means of `while B(k1,k2)` or `if ~B(k1,k2) break`, when I proposed a faster iteration as solution. The thing is, depending on how "dense" the true values are into `A` matrix, and also on the size of the matrix, the performance enhancement may go towards "simulate lazy and" or towards "rely on built-in performance optimization." I'm investigating this right now, with some real cases.

Comment: on second look, are you sure you've addressed the issue that @H.Muster raised? I'm not sure the accepted answer below is equivalent to your code.. can you explain in words what your original code is supposed to compute?

Comment: @Amro: Alright, I'm editing my original question now to reflect the purpose of the code. I'm pretty sure that what I asked for is OK, but one never knows... :-)

Comment: @CST-Link: hmm interesting. I appreciate the explanation, but to be honest I'm not very familiar with graph theory concepts, so I'm not gonna be much help there :\ I was suspicious because when I compared both solutions on random data (say `A = rand(10)<0.1`), the results were different some of the time (repeat [experiment](http://pastebin.com/b5uazTj4) multiple times)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small vectorization in the inner loop would be:

```
for k1 = 1:N, for k2 = 1:N
    B(k1,k2) = B(k1,k2) && ~all( A(k1,:) & A(:,k2)' );
end; end;
```

I'm not sure if there's a good way vectorize the outer loops.

**Edit**

Actually it's easy to vectorize both inner loops:

```
for k1 = 1:N
    B(k1,:) = ~all( bsxfun(@and, A(k1,:), A(:,:)' ) );
end;
B = A & B;
```

I am pretty sure that vectorizing everything would have to involve either matrix multiplication or a 3-d matrix which would take up a lot more space (assuming N is large).

Comment: This looks alright. I'll test it for speed. I'm sure it would be better than what I have now...

Comment: This *might* work if the inner expression uses the eager and operator '&' (for arrays) and not the lazy and operator '&&' (which works only on scalars). I could edit the answer, or you can edit it, as you want. Anyways, it's a new idea, and I'm testing it. Thanks for the time you take to tinker with this issue. :-)

Comment: also you might want to use BSXFUN instead of the REPMAT

Comment: @Amro You're right, thanks!. I didn't know about it before now.

Comment: @Amro: yes, built-ins work almost always faster than .m functions. Once I get my head around thrutheality's solution I will try this.

Comment: @trutheality: also you could move the `B(k,:) = B(k,:) & ...` out of the loop and do it once at the end. Another tiny improvement is to transpose once and store that, instead of doing it each iteration.. btw using BSXFUN is better because it avoid the replication, thus less memory consumption. I'm not sure speed-wise, although I suspect it also faster :)

Comment: Alright, it works ok. Thanks thrutheality and Amro for the synergy, I'm really grateful. :-)